# How to manage billing with WSO 2 AM (2.0.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I would like to combine WSO2 AM and DAS with billing function.
I tried to set it by referring to the following site, but the article did not correspond to WSO2 APIM(2.0.0).
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/
http://www.rukspot.com/Publishing_APIM_1100_Runtime_Statistics_to_DAS.html

I want to publish WSO 2 APIM(2.0.0) runtime statistics to DAS.
But,WSO2 AM(2.0.0) does not have admin-dashboard like WSO2 AM(1.10.X).

・Should I lower the WSO2 AM version?
・Is there a procedure / article based on WSO 2 AM (2.0.0)?
・Do you have my point should be noted?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: information was missing, I supplement it.WSO2 DAS 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

From 2.0.0 onwards, it's called `admin portal`, and the URL is `https://localhost:9443/admin`. However, analytics configurations are removed from Admin Portal UI. So you have to use `api-manager.xml` file to configure analytics.

Refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics) to configure analytics in 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that online service based on API Manager - [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - has API monetization and billing integration available out-of-box - just configure your billing plans and bank account and start collecting money: https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Enable+Monetization

Answer (score 0):

There´s a guide on the same blog that you linked

http://www.rukspot.com/configure_wso2_das_for_apim_analytics.html

This is for configuring DAS. If you only care about analytics data for apim I would recommend the new wso2am-analytics instead of the DAS. It's made specially for the apim and much easier to configure. See the guide that [Bhatiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805563/bhathiya) provided on how to configure wso2am-analytics.

Answer (score 0):

The [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/) is for APIM 1.10.0 and DAS 3.0.x. If you want to try this with APIM 2.0.0 you need to used the sample billing engine in this [repo](https://github.com/chamilaadhi/wso2-am-billing-engine). checkout the tag am-2.0 and check.